# Assembling Raid Arrays On New Kubuntu Install with mdadm

Tags: raid, mdadm

I have just re-installed Kubuntu on my machine recently, and have also installed mdadm to reassemble three raid arrays that I had previously. I didn't carry over any configuration files for these arrays, but installing mdadm automatically generated a conf file with what seems to be the correct information for the arrays.

Would I just need to run `mdadm --assemble --scan` as root to reassemble the arrays? That seems to be what is suggested, but I'm not sure if I need to include some pre-defined information on the arrays or if having multiple different raid arrays complicates the procedure.

This is what is contained in the automatically generated conf file:

```
# mdadm.conf
#
# !NB! Run update-initramfs -u after updating this file.
# !NB! This will ensure that initramfs has an uptodate copy.
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY /dev/md/4  metadata=1.2 UUID=9ff1aadf:fa7b7505:c8f39299:6647dfa1 name=Alice:4
ARRAY /dev/md/2  metadata=1.2 UUID=4b6b4aaf:eb9b31f3:d93da362:8e12e52c name=Alice:2
ARRAY /dev/md/3  metadata=1.2 UUID=0647af50:798149a3:4bcfe806:585ab84c name=Alice:3

# This configuration was auto-generated on Tue, 31 Aug 2021 02:48:58 -0400 by mkconf
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems I was being a bit paranoid and silly. On rebooting, the raid volumes were automatically detected as expected with no intervention needed. So to sort of answer my question, the automatically generated config file probably contains all the correct information on raid arrays, and `mdadm --assemble --scan` is probably the correct command to reassemble the arrays without restarting.